# Python - I need a collection with negative indices

Tags: python

I am "parsing" a 3d mesh, collecting repeating loops. The point of entry is not precisely known to me, but my algorithm "walks" the mesh in in two directions. First from 0 up, then from 0 down. I then need to convert collected information into a simple ordered collection.

I've managed to achieve a dict[int, SomeContainerFor3D] with keys ranging from -i to j.

Can I somehow sort it now and output into a 0-based collection? Or is there an easier way to go about it all?

EDIT: Because I can't attach the whole 3D mesh along with the actual algorithm, I built a model of the problem as MCVE:

```
import random

condo = ["Stoker", "Laundryboy", "Receptionist", "Mr Z", "Mr J", "The S Family", "The M Family", "Mr Rich"]
entry_point = random.randint(0, len(condo)-1)

occupants_map = {}
""":type : dict [int, string]"""    

def burglar(current):
    unknownlocation = entry_point+current
    if unknownlocation < len(condo) and unknownlocation >= 0:
        doorlabel = condo[unknownlocation]
        occupants_map[current] = doorlabel
        return True
    else: 
        return False


current = 0
while burglar(current) == True:
    current += 1


current = -1
while burglar(current) == True:
    current -= 1



print(occupants_map)
```

It prints out, oddly enough, positive keys in order, then negative keys in a weird unordered fashion.

Next, I will try to sort the dict and output the same occupants map to a sorted collection with only positive indices. I would still appreciate help with this.

Comment: The dict idea sounds like a good one to me.

Comment: What's wrong with the occasional `a[x+offset]`? Too much typing?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what was the problem you had with that approach? Specific code would be helpful.

Comment: @jsalonen The biggest problem is, I'm not fluent enough in Python to get the dict values out from the (unknown) lowest key to the (unknown) highest one, given that dict is unordered.

Comment: @DailyFrankPeter please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. A minimal example of code and input data, along with what you've tried, what you expected to happen and what happened instead would go a long way to making this question *actually answerable*.

Comment: Is your mesh sparse and does it always have a maximum and minimum?

Comment: @DailyFrankPeter A code example of what you want to do with the result will help generate better-quality answers.

Comment: a `list` is a collection with negative indices ...

Comment: @jsalonen It always has a maximum and minimum; in a special case of it being looped, the entry point ends up as the minimum (0) and the maximum equals the number of all edge loops -1 (i.e. only walks one way), otherwise the minimum is some finite negative integer and maximum some finite positive integer; 
I don't understand "sparse"

Comment: You can dump the contents of a dictionary to a list, sorting as you do so, using the `sorted()` built-in function.  Dictionaries are one of the most central and pervasive data structures in Python (and quite a number of other languages), so it's worth taking the time and effort to become comfortable with them.  Play around with them.  Read the tutorial and documentation on them.  See what the `.items()` dictionary method gets you.  I think you'll be able to figure out what you need.

Comment: @DailyFrankPeter by sparse I mean do you have a lot of - say - indices that hold 0 as value or you need to skip otherwise? Regardless, please add some code or examples to get more higher result answer.

Comment: @jsalonen MCVE added

Comment: @jonrsharpe MCVE added

Comment: @DailyFrankPeter could you add some clarification on what you expected? Dictionaries are *unordered*; if order matters you can use a `collections.OrderedDict` to retain insertion order, or just use e.g. `sorted(occupants_map.items())` to get a list of tuples `(key, value)` in key order.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I used a dictionary so that I can specify "indices" (keys) myself, in the order which is not dictated by anything except my mesh searching algorithm. The intention is to first collect (edit: "piece together") the data, and then put it in order, once I have the whole "picture" of the mesh.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want the output to be. Could you give an example dictionary, and the result you want from it? Do you just want to shift all keys up until the smallest is zero?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, that's exactly what I wanted; I also want the result to be iterable in order, I think I got enough hints by now to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so after hints I managed go from this raw result of the above code:

```
{0: 'The S Family', 1: 'The M Family', 2: 'Mr Rich', -1: 'Mr J', -5: 'Stoker', -4: 'Laundryboy', -3: 'Receptionist', -2: 'Mr Z'}
```

by means of:

```
dict2 = OrderedDict (sorted(occupants_map.items() ) )

list = dict2.values()
print(list)
```

to a list of:

```
['Stoker', 'Laundryboy', 'Receptionist', 'Mr Z', 'Mr J', 'The S Family', 'The M Family', 'Mr Rich']
```

Which is 0-based, ordered and iterable. And is what I wanted.

(I imagine I can also use the OrderedDict itself as an ordered and iterable collection, depending if I need easier access to my entry point, or to start of mesh.)

Comment: Note that the dictionary at the start of your answer *wasn't in the question*, and that the code that you did eventually put there wasn't really relevant to your query. It is hard to answer questions when they don't contain appropriate information.

Comment: The dictionary at the start of my answer was generated by the MCVE. It wasn't quoted in the question because it is a specific example of a random result printed by the MCVE. Should I still have put it there?

Comment: My point is that the core of your question was about transforming that dictionary into a different form; *how* it is created is not really relevant to that. By including the code to generate it, rather than just giving the dictionary and explaining the subsequent output you needed, you require readers to either run the code on the inputs or work out what it does, which *isn't actually necessary* to solve the problem. Had you just presented the dictionary, and clearly explained what you wanted from it, this question would probably have been answered in five minutes.